# Temporal Manager raster animation monthly instead of days in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, time, time-series

I have raster files on a per month scale over several years. I struggle to create an animation that shows monthly changes. I would like to have an animation showing each monthly raster file (and my other overlapping shape files).

I have manually added dates in the form of using the first day of the month and the last day of the month (e.g. January 2000 has the start date 2000-01-01 and end date 2000-01-31)

However, with the Temporal Manager the output won't be on a monthly-step scale. It always seems to convert a one-month step into days. With days, you'll eventually end up in between months and the output is not as desired.

For instance, starting on January 01-2001, the first step shows 2001-01-01 to 2000-01-31 and the second step shows 2001-01-31 to 2001-03-02. The output then only shows January and March, skipping the February raster. This is not only because of 28 days in February, I get similar results for other months, too.

I tried to use monthly steps as 1,04 or similar, but this does not consistently work, especially when you have long time series over many years. I would like to simply show each month at a time.

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/420064/temporal-controller-year-annual-data-step-skipping