# Temporal controller year / annual data step skipping

Tags: qgis, date, temporal-controller

I am working with a dataset which contains annual data for years in **non-QGIS format** i.e. 1951, 1955, etc from 1933 to 1955.

I have used `" to_date(  "year" , 'yyyy')"` to convert this data into QGIS-friendly data, so as to be read and analysed using the Temporal Controller.

Each date is now rendered as e.g. `1955-01-01` - which works with the Temporal Controller.

I have then added a simple Date point layer for when creating heatmaps and gifs - expressed as `format_date(@map_start_time, 'yyyy')`.

An issue I am facing, however, is that the 365.25 days by which a year is calculated eventually "overtakes", for want of a better phrase, the data I am working with.

As the image below shows, a point is eventually reached whereby a single year covers more than two years within the data. Here, for example, the map start date is 1937 but the data displayed - because, as far as I can tell, the date covers `1938-01-01 06:00:00` - is from 1938.

Has anyone else dealt with this / found a way to solve this when working with annual data on Temporal Controller?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

The trick is to use a date somewhere in the middle of the year, not at the beginning of the year and to set an event duration of less then a year in the layer property settings.

### How to make settings

1. From your `date`, create a new field `date2` by adding 6 months: `"date" + to_interval ('6 months')`
2. In the `Layer Properties / Temporal Tab` set `Field` to `date2` and for Event duration set something like `30 days`.
3. In the temporal controller interface, be sure to set `Animation range` from start to end of a year (like `1933-01-01` to `1955-12-31`) and `Step` to `1 year`.

### Explanation

Now only if end of June is included in the current frame's range, the relevant features will show on the map. So even if the time range of the current frame "shifts" in a way that it overlaps the divide between two years (like `1937-01-01 06:00:00` to `1938-01-01 06:00:00`), only 1937 will show up as `1937-06-30` is within this range, but not `1938-06-30`. If you had `1938-01-01`, however, both would show.

[image]

Comment: thanks for this trick/work around. It'd be great if QGIS could implement an official fix though, as this issue is currently present in 3.22. 1 month steps or durations, should NOT be fixed 30 days, but should respect actual month lengths.